# Assault II vs Hunter Pro

Tags: hunting, bow-hunting

Does anybody have experience with BOTH the Lone Wolf Assault II vs the Muddy Outdoors Hunter Pro? Please keep the discussion to this comparison. I'm leaning towards the muddy, it's lighter, and cheaper, and has a more comfortable seat. However, the platform does not look like it would be as quiet as the the LW.

Comment: I haven't used both, but I am curious.

Comment: I decided to go with the LW Assault II. Both are great stands but I decided to spend the extra bucks to buy a product manufactured and assembled here in the good ole USA.

Comment: Voted for a close because this is very opinion-based and kind of a purchase advice.